# How to thread-safely share an attribute between the beforePhase() and the afterPhase() methods of a PhaseListener?

Tags: multithreading, jsf, phaselistener

I need to share an attribute between the beforePhase() and the afterPhase() methods of my PhaseListener, for a same JSF request.

Is the following snippet thread-safe?

```java
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

  private MyObject o = null;

  @Override
  public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (condition) {
      o = new MyObject();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (o != null) {
      o.process();
      o = null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
  }

}
```

If not, what are other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not threadsafe. There's only one phase listener instance applicationwide which is shared across multiple requests. Basically, a phase listener is like an `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean.

Just set it as a context attribute.

```
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

  @Override
  public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (condition) {
      event.getFacesContext().setAttribute("o", new MyObject());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    MyObject o = (MyObject) event.getFacesContext().getAttribute("o");
    if (o != null) {
      o.process();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) for this, but it tends to have issues in environments having different classloaders, to name it: **memory leak**. Be sure to check for that in the given environment...

Also, you should make it sure that if the processing can be interrupted (e.g. exception...) between the `beforePhase()` and `afterPhase()` methods, the `ThreadLocal` should be handled appropriately...

This is what it would look like:

```java
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

  //if null is a valid value, no initial setting is needed
  private ThreadLocal<Object> myStateObject = new ThreadLocal<Object> ();

  @Override
  public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {

    //might be needed, to guarrantee no residue from an aborted processing is in there
    myState.set(null); 
    if (condition) {
      myState.set(<Object representing the state>);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    try {
        Object stateObject = myState.get();
        if (stateObejct!=null) {
          //do what you have to 
        }
    } finally {
       //to be sure
       myState.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

In [this article](http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/work_around_openinsessionviewphaselistener_for_filters) the author uses ThreadLocal too...

Also, [this article is also a great eye-opener](http://www.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/jsf-phaselistener-instances-must-be-made-thread-safe), explaining why not to share mutable instance-level information:

> One thing to remember though, is that PhaseListener instances are application-wide Singletons that are referenced by the JSF Lifecycle, which itself is an application-wide Singleton.

**EDIT** just saw Boolean got updated to Object, adjusted example

Comment: Don't waste a `ThreadLocal` variable as long as you don't need it elsewhere in the code.